Slow Performance with conda command, pip command, and Importing Packages in Python
I've been experiencing significant slowdowns when using commands such as conda list, pip list, or importing packages like torch after entering Python. However, running other Linux commands like nvidia-smi or ps -f -p PID is very smooth. Is there something wrong with my conda environment?
I tried using another new virtual environment, but it still doesn't seem to run those commands right away. My GPU and CPU usage are normal and not overloaded.
